# When using notify-send inside some process runner such as CRON or PM2, notifications don't appear

Tags: node.js, notifications, cron, pm2

I am using [`node-notifier`](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier), a Node.js library which allows cross-platfrom desktop notifications. For Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome3 (gubuntu distro), which I use, it uses `notify-send` command to send notifications.

From library source code:

```
var notifier = 'notify-send'
...
utils.command(notifier, argsList, callback)
```

`utils.command`:

```
module.exports.command = function(notifier, options, cb) {
  notifier = shellwords.escape(notifier);

  return cp.exec(notifier + ' ' + options.join(' '), function(
    error,
    stdout,
    stderr
  ) {
    if (error) return cb(error);
    cb(stderr, stdout);
  });
};
```

It works when script is ran from user's CLI, but if I run this code via CRON (`crontab -e`) or `PM2`, then these notifications are not visible to end user. The rest of script works just fine.

What does actually happen? Do process runners break something? Is it due lack of access to environment variables?

Comment: Where should these jobs' output be displayed? A single user can have 0 to N sessions running on the same host while the job is executed, so picking the right place is probably impossible. Why don't you just send a mail (as is the usual modus operandi for cronjobs)?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Because I want this script to run on startup and notify server about it. The most elegant solution is to show green notification upon successful ping, and red upon failure.

Comment: I have no clue who's startup you are talking about and where you see a server that needs to be notified.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Basically I have a server somewhere listening for requests. When I turn on my PC and boot to desktop environment, crontab should run this script via `@reboot`, which then sends request to the server, if response was 200, it shows green notification, if response was >=400, it shows red notification.

Comment: Where should it display this if you are not even logged in? Normally, after booting, crond is started, but no user is logged in. I think you are using the wrong approach to this problem: Run the status check when you log in instead! There are various ways to achieve this, most desktop environments have an "autostart" registry or something like that.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt same issue when using desktop environment provided process runner (For Gnom3 I used this approach: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172179/gnome-shell-running-shell-script-after-session-starts)

Comment: Okay. So basically, your first approach is broken by design and your second attempt doesn't work, and that is all that is known to the world of your second approach. Sorry, but reread the guideline for asking good questions and compare that with the current state here.